# PIC16F1503 CLKOUT doesn't work

Tags: pic, clock, assembler

I have this simple program:

```
#include <p16f1503.inc>
__CONFIG _CONFIG1, _FOSC_INTOSC & _WDTE_OFF & _PWRTE_ON & _MCLRE_OFF & _CP_OFF & _BOREN_OFF & _CLKOUTEN_ON
__CONFIG _CONFIG2, _WRT_OFF & _STVREN_OFF & _LVP_OFF

    org      0x00
    goto     setup

setup
    banksel  OSCCON
    movlw    b'01101010'  ; Int. osc. 4 MHz
    movwf    OSCCON

    banksel  OPTION_REG
    BCF      OPTION_REG, TMR0CS 

    banksel  ANSELA
    clrf     ANSELA   
    banksel  TRISA                    
    clrf     TRISA   

    goto     main_loop


main_loop
    nop
    goto     main_loop

    end
```

What I would like to do is to enable CLKOUT pin, but it doesn't work... Am I missing something?

I am using:

- IDE: MPLAB X IDE v1.20
- Compiler: MPASM v5.45

and integrated software simulator...

**[EDIT]**

CLKOUT works just fine.. But sadly not in simulator.... Can someone explain reason for this behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the MPLAB SIM documentation sums up the issue perfectly:

> MPLAB SIM only simulates to the register level, not the pin level,
> e.g., RB0 represents the value in bit0 of the PORTB register, not the
> value on the pin named RB0.
>
> This makes sense as the simulator is a software model, and not actual device hardware.

Since CLKOUT is based on the chip hardware and isn't a SFR, it won't be simulated.

Comment: I *hate* using SE sites with iOS. The site is almost unusable!

Comment: Great! Exactly that was the missing piece of information I was looking for...